# Arch Linux - Add Multiple IP Addresses to Network

Tags: linux, networking

I'm trying to add multiple ip addresses to arch linux server.

Since I have only one network card with interface eth0 I think I need to add virtual interfaces like eth0:1 etc..

I have tried using this following syntax in /etc/rc.conf, but it seems to trow a bunch of errors:
(note for this example I have omitted the ips for security)

```
eth0="eth0 x.x.x.x netmask x.x.x.x broadcast x.x.x.x"
eth0_0="eth0:0 x.x.x.x netmask x.x.x.x broadcast x.x.x.x"
INTERFACES=(lo eth0 eth0_0)
gateway="default gw x.x.x.x"
ROUTES=(gateway)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not use the [ip](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ip) command e.g.

```
ip addr add 10.9.8.7/32 dev eth0
```

or whatever you need in a suitable init script ?

Answer (score 1):

### Basic IP Aliasing with netcfg

With [netcfg](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Netcfg), IP aliasing is managed by running the same `ip` commands you would use if you were doing it manually:

```
POST_UP='ip addr add 72.20.27.234/30 dev eth0 label eth0:1'
PRE_DOWN='ip addr del 72.20.27.234/30 dev eth0 label eth0:1'
```

That's it. It just works.

Here's a netcfg ethernet profile to start with:

```
CONNECTION='ethernet'
DESCRIPTION='ifconfig like a boss'
INTERFACE='eth0'
IP='static'
ADDR='192.168.183.118'
NETMASK='255.255.255.252'
GATEWAY='192.168.183.117'
DNS=('8.8.8.8' '208.67.222.222')
```

Now put that profile in a place like `/etc/network.d/staminus`.  Let's test it.

```
netcfg staminus
```

If you still have any network configuration in `rc.conf`, remove it. It's deprecated. Just add `net-profiles` in your daemons list. We can tell netcfg to use this profile by default, when the system boots. In `/etc/conf.d/netcfg`:

```
NETWORKS=(staminus)
```

Now append to your ethernet profile some `POST_UP` and `PRE_DOWN` commands as described earlier. Then stroke that glorious neckbeard.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [the archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Configuring_Network#IP_address_aliasing); it has a description of how to do this.

Comment: Yeah, already did. But I was trying to avoid using netcfg is there any other way to do this in rc.conf it self ?

Comment: Not that I know of, but I'm not an expert on archlinux. If you do find one, I'm sure they'd appreciate it if you update the wiki.

It would have been very helpful if you included in your question that you'd already tried the recommended way - since you didn't, it looked as if you just didn't know it existed.

Comment: So far I only found references to netcfg but I'm trying to find a simpler way of doing this =)

Comment: Also, you can see the post on the forum, https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1133151